# How can I set/find my file and directory in Excel vba (xlwings)?

Tags: excel, vba, xlwings

I was trying to utilize Excel vba with Python code with xlwings, I have an Excel file and a Python(.py) file in the same folder.
But when I run my vba, it showed "sh: /hello: No such file or directory".

I don't know what happened, and how can I set the file path.

I was trying the very basic code.

```
Sub Call_Python_Function()

    RunPython ("import hello; hello.world()")

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your python file (.py) and excel file (.xlsm) saved to the same folder? The example from the docs (https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html) uses that, so I think that's worth trying

Comment: Thank you for your reply first! And yes, they are in the same folder, and it works after I put the file name in the xlwings -> Pythonpath. (But I don't think that's the problem) Another problem came up, after it ran, I didn't get any error message, but nothing showed up. : (

Comment: Can you elaborate on "After I ran it...nothing showed up"? Did you have that output go anywhere? Like `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox`?